# How do I stop Prolog mode from jumping to the Prolog REPL when consulting the buffer?

Tags: major-mode, repl

Suppose I am using Prolog mode with the Prolog REPL started as an inferior process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Whenever I "consult" (i.e. evaluate) the Prolog mode buffer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (`(prolog-consult-buffer)`), I will end up in the Prolog REPL. Is there a way to prevent this? I want to stay in the source code when I "consult" the buffer; I don't want to go to the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that this behavior is hardcoded into prolog.el. The function responsible for moving to the REPL is [`prolog-goto-prolog-process-buffer`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27/lisp/progmodes/prolog.el#L2610-L2614). For the moment, I will be adding this hack into `~/.emacs` as a stopgap solution:

```
(eval-after-load
  "prolog"
  (advice-add 'prolog-consult-buffer
              :around
              (lambda (f &rest args)
                (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'prolog-goto-prolog-process-buffer)
                           (lambda () nil)))
                  (apply f args)))))
```

This effectively disables the call to `prolog-goto-prolog-process-buffer` in `prolog-consult-buffer` by redefining `prolog-goto-prolog-process-buffer` to do nothing (`(lambda () nil)`) when it is used by `prolog-consult-buffer`.